# Constructor is not receiving values from object that is created inside

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am building a crawler, where the values can be stored in the database.
For that I built a reference table as shown in the `ShowCast` class.
Unfortunately I can't get these values filled.
The `CrawlcastAsync` and `CrawlShowAsync` methods works.
But the constructor receives nothing

```
    Console.WriteLine("Constructor print");
    Console.WriteLine(show.Name);
```

And that's why the rest of the code is also empty

```
    public async Task CrawlShow(Show show, Cast cast)
    {
        showCast = new ShowCast(show, cast);
        
    }
```

See below my Application

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;

class Show
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long ShowId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Show show { get; set; }

    public Show(long ShowId)
    {
        CrawlShowAsync(ShowId);
    }

     public async Task CrawlShowAsync(long ShowId)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();        
        string url = "https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + ShowId;
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        show = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Show>(response);
    }

}

class Cast
{
    public Person? Person { get; set; }
    public List<Cast> dataCast { get; set; }
    public Cast(long ShowId)
    {
        CrawlcastAsync(ShowId);        
    }

    public async Task CrawlcastAsync(long ShowId)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string urlcast = "https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + ShowId + "/cast";
        string responseCast = await client.GetStringAsync(urlcast);
        dataCast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cast>>(responseCast);
    }
}

class ShowCast
{
    public long ShowId { get; set; }
    public List<long> CastIds { get; set; }

    public ShowCast(Show show, Cast cast)
    {
        this.ShowId = show.ShowId;
        var dataCast = cast.dataCast;
        foreach(var item in dataCast)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Person.PersonId);
            CastIds.Add(item.Person.PersonId);
        }
    }
}

class Crawler
{
    public Cast cast { get; set; }
    public Show show { get; set; }  
    public ShowCast showCast { get; set; }

    public Crawler(long ShowId)
    {
        show = new Show(ShowId);
        cast = new Cast(ShowId);
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor print");
        Console.WriteLine(show.Name);
        CrawlShow(show, cast);
    }
    
    public async Task CrawlShow(Show show, Cast cast)
    {
        showCast = new ShowCast(show, cast);
        
    }
}

class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long PersonId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("birthday")]
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    
}

public class Starter    
{
    
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler(530);
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("End of COde");
   
    }
}
```

Why is `Console.WriteLine(item.Person.PersonId);` not printing the values?

**PART2**

Based on the comments of Oris I have now this but this is also not printing `Console.WriteLine(show.Name);` and also at `await showCast.start();` I receive the error: does not contain a definition for start and no accessible extension method

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.Metrics;


class Show
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long ShowId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Show show { get; set; }

    public Show(long ShowId)
    {

    }

    public async Task CrawlShowAsync(long ShowId)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string url = "https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + ShowId;
        string response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        show = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Show>(response);
    }

}

class Cast
{
    public Person? Person { get; set; }
    public List<Cast> dataCast { get; set; }
    //public Cast(long ShowId);

    public Cast(long ShowId)
    {
        //CrawlcastAsync(ShowId);        
    }

    public async Task CrawlcastAsync(long ShowId)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string urlcast = "https://api.tvmaze.com/shows/" + ShowId + "/cast";
        string responseCast = await client.GetStringAsync(urlcast);
        dataCast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cast>>(responseCast);
    }

}

class Person
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long PersonId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("birthday")]
    public string Birthday { get; set; }

}

class ShowCast
{
    public long ShowId { get; set; }
    public List<long> CastIds { get; set; }


    public ShowCast(Show show, Cast cast)
    {
        this.ShowId = show.ShowId;
        var dataCast = cast.dataCast;
        foreach (var item in dataCast)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Person.PersonId);
            CastIds.Add(item.Person.PersonId);
        }
    }


}

class Crawler
{
    public Cast cast { get; set; }
    public Show show { get; set; }
    public ShowCast showCast { get; set; }

    public Crawler(long ShowId)
    {
        show = new Show(ShowId);
        cast = new Cast(ShowId);
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor print");
    }

    public async Task CrawlShow(Show show, Cast cast)
    {
        showCast = new ShowCast(show, cast);
        //await showCast.start();

    }

    public async Task start(long ShowId)
    {
        await show.CrawlShowAsync(ShowId);

        await cast.CrawlcastAsync(ShowId);

        // now Show is loaded
        Console.WriteLine(show.Name);


        // Cast is also loaded
        CrawlShow(show, cast);
    }
}



public class Starter
{

    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler(530);
        await crawler.start(530);

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("End of COde");

    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `Task` returning methods from inside the constructor is an anti-pattern. Don't design code like this to start with, and definitely don't do it repeatedly across multiple classes.

Comment: When a class is constructed there is default code in the Net Library that is run before and after the custom constructor code like in your case SHOW method.  So your method CrawlShowAsync is being run before the class is fully constructed.  Also constructors do not return an values.  Your code is returning an HTTP Response.  For code like this it is better to put into a Static Method in the class rather than the constructor.

Comment: I want to do this the object oriented way instead of using static methods, how would you approach that?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor returns and doesnot wait for Task to be completed.
Therefore, you can just put asynchronous logic in a separate method, not on constructor.

```
class Show
{


    public Show(long ShowId)
    {
        //CrawlShowAsync(ShowId);
  
    }

}

class Cast
{

    public Cast(long ShowId)
    {
        //CrawlcastAsync(ShowId);        
    }

}

class ShowCast
{


    public ShowCast(Show show, Cast cast)
    {
        this.ShowId = show.ShowId;
        var dataCast = cast.dataCast;
        foreach(var item in dataCast)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Person.PersonId);
            CastIds.Add(item.Person.PersonId);
        }
    }


}

class Crawler
{
    public Cast cast { get; set; }
    public Show show { get; set; }  
    public ShowCast showCast { get; set; }

    public Crawler(long ShowId)
    {
        show = new Show(ShowId);
        cast = new Cast(ShowId);
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor print");
        //Console.WriteLine(show.Name);
        //CrawlShow(show, cast);
    }
    
    public async Task CrawlShow(Show show, Cast cast)
    {
        showCast = new ShowCast(show, cast);
        await showCast.start();
        
    }

    public async Task start(long ShowId) {
      await show.CrawlShowAsync(ShowId);

      await cast.CrawlcastAsync(ShowId);

      // now Show is loaded
      Console.WriteLine(show.Name);


      // Cast is also loaded
      CrawlShow(show, cast);
    }
}



public class Starter    
{
    
    public static async Task Main()
    {
        Crawler crawler = new Crawler(530);
        await crawler.start(530);

        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine("End of COde");
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your comment I I have now edited my code but this is also not printing `Console.WriteLine(show.Name);` and also at `await showCast.start();` I receive the error: does not contain a definition for start and no accessible extension method